# Save form data in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-view, route-provider

how can i save data from 1 view to another in angularjs?

i did $rootScope

Comment: Still have not been able to solve this. I don't feel like re-making my entire webapp just to be able to save the form input somehow. There must be a quick way of doing it. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, you use 2 different controllers for each view (or one for the view and none for the root view).

The problem is that Angular can't share data between controllers like that.

You either have to use a service/factory, or use the rootscope, but not as you did, rather with `broadcast` and `emit`

If I were you I would use a service.

**EDIT** Here you go, a service for you :

```
(function() {
'use strict';
angular
    .module('YourModuleName')
    .factory('CountriesService', CountriesService);
CountriesService.$inject = ['Your', 'dependencies', 'here', 'in', 'string'];
/* @ngInject */
function CountriesService(your, dependencies, here, not, in, string) {

    var service = {
        setCountries: setCountries,
        getCountries: getCountries
    };

    var vm = this;
    vm.countries = []; // Or maybe an object ?
    // ... List of other variables you need to store.

    return service;
    ////////////////
    function setCountries(listOfCountries) {
        vm.countries = listOfCountries;
    }

    function getCountries() {
        return vm.countries;
    }
}
})();
```

This will store your variables. In your controller you add `CountriesService` as a dependency, to save you use `CountriesService.setCountries` and to load you use `CountriesService.getCountries`. Be aware that refreshing the page will delete all the data !

**EDIT NUMBER 2**
If you're scared of [John papa guidelines](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md), here is a simple service you can use in the same file you put your controller :

```
    app.factory('CountryControl', function(your, dependencies) {

        var service = {
            setCountries: setCountries,
            getCountries: getCountries
        };


        this.countries = []; // Or maybe an object ?
        // ... List of other variables you need to store.

        return service;
        ////////////////
        function setCountries(listOfCountries) {
            this.countries = listOfCountries;
        }

        function getCountries() {
            return this.countries;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I only have 1 controller, and I pass it in the routeProvider for the details page. I really have no idea how to set up a service out of my code. Could you provide some examples? By the way, should I upload my whole website folder somewhere for you to see? Maybe it's easier when you see the page in front of you.

Comment: Nah I'm good, I'll just post you a service there and show you how to use it. You should dig into that, you will find many tutorials online. Ok so, wait a sec, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I'm a some-what beginner at AngularJS; and your solution might work (I don't know), but it seems too difficult for me to implement. I need to change so much on all the files to make it work then I guess. I always used scopes and rootscopes before :/

Comment: If you're a beginner I strongly advise you to read John papa angular 1 styleguide. Basically, it's someone who tells you how to code. The service you see here is a template from his templates. But still, if you don't want to, I strongly advise you to learn more about services. They're as important as controllers. I've been there too and it seems complicated, but it's not. If you find it too difficult, see the second edit of my post.

Comment: Good solution bro .. but you don't implement the broadcast and emit services ?

Comment: I am not a fan of `broadcast` and `emit`, I'd rather use a service or a factory. I only use it in rare cases. And when I do so, I don't use a service, just a `rootScope` dependency !

Answer (score 0):

I have an app that does this more or less. A service fixes this nicely AND creates a mechanism such that you can do this anywhere in your app.

First, I would recommend not trying to manage this with scope. Just put an object on your controller (myFormObj), and add the properties you want to it (name, rank, serialnumber, etc).

Then bind the input fields of the form, to the properties in that object (as opposed to scope vars). So your ng-model things would look like myCtl.formObj.name, and so on.

When the user triggers the event that changes the view, save a COPY (angular.copy) of that formObj off to the side, usually in a Service (think FormStateService or something). FormStateService could do nothing more than hold a simple array.

```
this.forms = { 'TheNameOfYourForm' : theFormObjToSave };
```

So, when the user triggers that event that leaves the form, you just do this:

formStateSvc.forms [ 'NameOfMyForm' ] = angular.copy ( theFormObj );

When the user comes back to the original view and the controller initializes, you just ask the formStateSvc:

```
if ( 'NameOfMyForm' in formStateSvc.forms ) {
   this.formObj = formStateSvc.forms [ 'NameOfMyForm' ];
}
```

Voila, your old form state is restored.

More robustly, you could create "addForm, removeForm" methods etc, you could ensure against things like undefined, and you could make the rebind to the former state implicit (when your form's controller inits, just ask it to restore the state if there's any to restore). So your controller would just have:

this.formObj = formStateSvc.rebindOldDataIfItExists ( 'MyFormName' );

You get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is to create a value provider object and publish it on scope:

```
//Create value provider object
app.value("FormObj", {});

app.controller("myController", function($scope, FormObj) {
    //Publish on scope
    $scope.FormObj = FormObj;
});
```

Then have the `ng-model` directives use that object:

```
Name <input ng-model="FormObj.name"><br>
Rank <input ng-model="FormObj.rank"><br>
SerialNum <input ng-model="FormObj.ssnum"><br>
```

The value object is a singleton which persists for the life of the application. Changes to the contents of the object will be retained and available to other controllers and will survive changes to the view.

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/UmRtMbebaqDjsRgisjH8?p=preview)